jenkins multibranch pipeline issue
Started by user Lokendra Pratap

git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/lib/jenkins/caches/git-fc88e8256d42fe44e63b54f6638234f2/.git # timeout=10
Setting origin to https://github.com/LokendraDevOps/Jenkins_Assignmnet.git
git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/LokendraDevOps/Jenkins_Assignmnet.git # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
git --version # timeout=10
git --version # 'git version 2.40.1'
git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials
git fetch --tags --force --progress -- origin +refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/ # timeout=10
Seen branch in repository origin/develop
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen branch in repository origin/prod
Seen branch in repository origin/test
Seen 4 remote branches
Obtained Jenkinsfile from 6fd92753ca9a29ff851e3e0e7eb09ce091b661e8
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 4: Expected string literal @ line 4, column 15.
stage {
^

WorkflowScript: 4: Stage does not have a block @ line 4, column 9.
stage {
^
WorkflowScript: 12: Triggers definitions cannot have blocks @ line 12, column 9.
scm {
^
WorkflowScript: 17: Multiple occurrences of the stages section @ line 17, column 5.
stages {
^
4 errors
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1107)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox$Scope.parse(GroovySandbox.java:163)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:190)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:175)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:635)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:581)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:335)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)

Finished: FAILURE
when i build using below file showing error
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage {
            scm {
               git 'https://github.com/LokendraDevOps/Jenkins_Assignmnet.git'
               branch 'develop' 
            }
        }
    }
    triggers {
        scm {
            branches { "develop" }
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Copy to Test Node (if successful)') {
            when {
                expression { return $currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS' }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'rsync -avz -e ssh . 172.31.21.36:/home/ubuntu/Job-3'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy to Prod (if successful)') {
            when {
                expression { return $currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS' }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'rsync -avz -e ssh . 172.31.19.138:/home/ubuntu/Job-3'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Several issues with the Jenkinsfile: your stage keyword needs a name in line 4 and its also missing steps & script:
stage('Clone repository') {
    steps {
        script {
            git branch: 'develop', url: 'https://github.com/LokendraDevOps/Jenkins_Assignmnet.git'
        }
    }
}

Your expressions don't need to return anything, just having the expression is enough. Also it's best to have the triggers at the start of the pipeline. Try this changed jenkinsfile:
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        scm 'develop'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clone repository') {
            steps {
                script {
                    git branch: 'develop', url: 'https://github.com/LokendraDevOps/Jenkins_Assignmnet.git'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Copy to Test Node (if successful)') {
            when {
                expression { currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS' }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'rsync -avz -e ssh . 172.31.21.36:/home/ubuntu/Job-3'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy to Prod (if successful)') {
            when {
                expression { currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS' }
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'rsync -avz -e ssh . 172.31.19.138:/home/ubuntu/Job-3'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

